# how do i get the position in the original string where the last character of the captured substring found

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Guys this is my original string,
'010000111'

i need to find this pattern '10000111'.So i used below regular expression to do that.

Match m = Regex.Match("010000111", @"[1][0][0][0][0][1]+");

I get the correct answer from this Regex.But the problem is i need to get the position in the original string where the last character of the captured string,that's mean according to my example my captured pattern is '10000111'
According to the captured pattern my last index is 7,but when it is compare to the original string it is 8.

i used lastIndexOf('1') function.but it gives the index of the captured string.

can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex to do this.

To check if the string contains another, use the `someString.IndexOf("someOtherString")` method. This will give you the index of the first character in the sequence.

To get the position of the last char, all you have to do is sum the length of the tested string and subtract 1:

```
var firstString = "010000111";
var secondString = "10000111";

var positionOfSecondOverFirst = firstString.IndexOf(secondString); // 1

var firstContainsSecond = (positionOfSecondOverFirst >= 0); // true

var positionOfLastChar = positionOfSecondOverFirst + secondString.Length - 1; // 8
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Any Particular reason why you want to use a regex? I think what you're trying to accomplish can be done by simply using `IndexOf`

```
public static int GetIndex()
{
    const string input = "010000111";
    const string substring = "10000111";

    var startIndex = input.IndexOf(substring);
    if (startIndex != -1)
    {
        return startIndex + substring.Length;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method below:

```
private int findLastIndex(string s1, string s2)
{
  if (s1.indexOf(s2)>-1)
  {
    return s1.indexOf(s2) + s2.Length - 1;
  }
  else
    return -1; //not found
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer

Comment: I am glad to help you. I appreciate if you select my answer as the correct one, if you used my reply in your code..